# How to checkout external git library in a svn repository

Tags: git, svn

I am working on a project which uses svn repository. Currently, we need to add a third party library which is on git. Is it possible add a specific git tag as an external in svn repository property? If it is, please let me know how to achieve it.

Thanks,

Rong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would need to use some composing software that can speak SVN and Git. Neither has the possibility to include a repo of the other by default.